# List of all shorcut keys used by windows explorer?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

I'm using Flash and everytime I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> combination, an old software I have installed tries to open.

I think that there are a windows shortcut with a keyboard shortcut assigned to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> .

It is there a way to find these assigned shortcut?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the free utility [Shortcut Key Explorer](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/shortcutkeys/) from [RJL Software](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/).

You can also check what program opens up and via the start-menu right click that program and choose properties and remove/edit the shortcut.

Comment: I just found the shorcut link file manually.
But I was concerned that would happen if the. Lnk were well hidden in the depths of the disc.thank you very much

Comment: Yes, you can also change the .lnk in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` directly by right clicking and choosing properties. There are also script who run through all the places where there are .lnk files and show the shortcuts. (but a simple program is always simpler)

Comment: +1 for helping me find random shortcuts I never knew existed